# Push notification receive and handle

Tags: iphone, push, push-notification

I have two problems.

1. I implement notification, install in my phone but when I send notification from provider, I didn't receive any notification.  But when I use another phone I receive notification. Is there any setting for receiving notification?
2. Where in my code I must implement code that must run when I click on "View button" on notification alert?

Answer (score 1):

1) Once there is an app installed that accepts notifications there will be a "Notifications" item in the iPhone Preferences just under "Wi-Fi".

2) There is nothing specific other than the standard APS registration on startup.  On an application basis the app may want to connect to the server to provide feedback that the notification was received and the app was run.

The app should be using:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
```

Not

```
- (void)applicationDidFinishLaunching:(UIApplication *)application
```

Comment: if we use this method - (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions will our application shows the views